# No Definition for System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

i try to register a hotkey for a windows mobile application but i can't override System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc because there's no definition found.

What am I missing to override this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [MessageWindows class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.messagewindow%28VS.80%29.aspx) as the target for RegisterHotKey call.  You can [overrride its WndProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.messagewindow.wndproc%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and use that to receive the hotkey messages.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's not possible. If you look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form_methods%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), the `WndProc` method doesn't have that *Compact Framework* icon. That means it isn't available.

For reference, [`Form.WndProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.wndproc%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) lists the following target platforms:

> Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP SP2, Windows XP Media Center Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows XP Starter Edition, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2000 SP4, Windows Millennium Edition, Windows 98

Whereas [`Control.Update`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) lists:

> Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP SP2, Windows XP Media Center Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows XP Starter Edition, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2000 SP4, Windows Millennium Edition, Windows 98, Windows CE, Windows Mobile for Smartphone, Windows Mobile for Pocket PC

[This post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/532d40e3-69a9-4978-83d6-5b84a3f29062/) also suggests it isn't possible, and points to a workaround [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/netcfteam/archive/2005/05/23/421143.aspx). There's also an article over at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/smart/CF_kiosk_mode.aspx) that seems to make use of that workaround.

Comment: It should be, but i havn't got a definition. I found a few samples which use WndProc on WindowsMobile, but i don't know where they got the definition for wndproc.